# Is it illegal to say the police won't help?

Tags: canada, police

This is a silly question but is it illegal to threaten someone that the police would not come if they were called?

My ex-landlord threatened to remove my belongings. I said I would have to call the police and he retorted he works with the police and they're his friends. On a separate incident the landlord entered my suite without notice and I filed a police report. I mentioned that the landlord claimed the police are friends with him and the operator said something like it's a serious threat for someone to claim they can get away with things because they're friends with a police officer. This was just the operator and when I spoke with the police officer he basically just said noted and didn't want to talk about it. (For clarity, I already knew the landlord IS NOT a police officer himself, but he was trying to intimidate me by saying his job crosses paths with police a lot).

Is there a law regarding this? Or is there more a professional subject?

Comment: What are the single-party recording laws in your jurisdiction? I used a shop once where the owners had taken a loan from an illegal loan shark, and when they fell behind in their payments and the loan shark was going to seize their property by force, he told them not to look for help from the police, as he paid them off. The shop-owners had recorded this conversation, which they took to the police, and it didn't end well for the loan shark.